# Согласование подлежащего и сказуемого

Tags: общие-вопросы

В предложении: В структуру райпо входят(или входит) шесть предприятий общественного питания и два по производству собственной продукции.
На мой взгляд, нужно входит, так как подлежащее выражено сочетанием количественного числительного с неодушевл. существительным или же здесь множественность (6 предприятий и 2 предприятия)? Подскажите.

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Если вы после этого не будете раскрывать, что это за предприятия, и смысл сообщения в указании их количества, логичнее так: в структуру **входит** столько-то таких предприятий и ещё вот столько других, т.е. не "они входят" в таком-то количестве, а "их входит" столько. Если же вы собираетесь после этого их перечислить, то сигналом к этому послужит "**входят**" (они имеют лицо).

Comment: спасибо, все поняла.